# How to open inner pages within the same html code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a login page and a side navigation where i'm trying to allow the user to move between these navigation and each one will change the center div with its own content and when the user click on another option the center will be replaced. 
but each time I try jquerys or javascript I succeed with placing the content but when i click multiple options the previous ones are still there and the new content is stacking up. 
I hope that I made my point clear

This is my navigation

```
<table id="navlist">
    <tr>
        <td><a href='#'><i class="fas fa-home"></i><br>Home</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href='#'><i class="fab fa-autoprefixer"></i><br>System Requirements</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i><br>FAQs</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href='#'><i class="fas fa-cogs"></i><br>System Support</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-wpforms"></i><br>Forms</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And the javascript that I tried

```
function SwapDivsWithClick(div1, div2) {
    firstDiv = document.getElementById(div1);
    secondDiv = document.getElementById(div2);
    if (secondDiv.style.display == "none") {
        firstDiv.style.display = "none";
        secondDiv.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        firstDiv.style.display = "block";
        secondDiv.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Please if anyone has better idieas I'm all ears

Comment: maybe it will more easy to use html template system like smarty or twig. You define a layout common to each page and then make one html file for each navigation item's page heritate from the layout

Answer (score 0):

You can have it using the `jquery` and `html`.

The structure can be as below (`target-id` is the custom attribute):

```
<div class="navigation">
    <ul class="navigation-section">
        <li>
            <a href="#" target-id="home">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" target-id="system-requirements">System Requirements</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" target-id="faqs">FAQs</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" target-id="system-support">System Support</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Their respective info I have saved it in the HTML itself

```
<div class="hide">
    <div id="home">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ex eam dictas melius laboramus, id vel mazim qualisque posidonium. Pri an brute temporibus appellantur,
        qui error fierent et, et mei homero nostrud.
    </div>
    <div id="system-requirements">
        Latine voluptua maluisset pri ex, ea alienum ancillae assueverit pri, ne mea elitr scripserit referrentur. Brute dissentiunt
        ut sea, quaeque epicurei lobortis qui an. Ut eum wisi illud omnesque, oporteat accusamus mei in. Ne offendit detraxit
        repudiandae his. Ex stet ceteros noluisse quo, sit at fierent dissentiet.
    </div>
    <div id="faqs">
        Duo ad verear interesset, harum forensibus necessitatibus vis cu, ne mutat vitae noluisse sed. Cu nec maluisset scriptorem.
        Sit dicat dolorem interpretaris et, cum ut erat melius legendos, duo an nibh libris.
    </div>
    <div id="system-support">
        Mea mucius facete verterem ea, mei modo reprimique reformidans eu, et commune voluptaria nam. Vim quas aliquando cu. Cu qui
        nullam imperdiet aliquando. Eius nonumy an pro, mel ne modo senserit. Nam id vero facilisi, partem propriae nam et.
    </div>
</div>
```

Using jquery one can handle the `click` event:

```
function menuClick() {
    $('.navigation-section a').on('click', function () {
        var targetId = $(this).attr('target-id');
        $('.content-info').text($('#' + targetId).text());
    });
}
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/e9czteeb/1/)